# Need to group a Vertex by a Vertex which is saved as a property in that Vertex in Neptune DB using gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have two vertices Workspace and Customer in Neptune DB and Workspace has Customer as property.  It is like having foreign key as Customer in Workspace in RDBMS. I want to group Workspace by one of the Customer's  property. In Workspace customer is saved with unique id given by Neptune with key as customer and value as unique id of that entity.

In the below query , projecting customer which is basically an attribute of Workspace vertex having value as unique id of Customer vertex and trying to group by firstName which is a property of Customer vertex and finally grouping by count step. I'm not sure if this is the way. Please help me with this.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Workspace').
      has('customer').
      project('entity').
        by(values('customer')).
      group().
        by('entity.firstName').
        by(count());
```

Answer (score 1):

The data model doesn't make much sense.  In a graph, there's no need for foreign keys.  Instead, you would typically have an edge between the Workspace and Customer vertices.

```
(Workspace) <- [usedBy] - (Customer)
```

Where 'usedBy' would be the edge type (or label) of the edge connecting the two.  If following that pattern, you could do a query such as:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Workspace').
    group().by(
        in('usedBy').values('entity.firstName'))
```

and then if you wanted the total count of workspaces per customer, you could then add `count()` on to the end such that:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Workspace').
    group().
        by(in('usedBy').values('entity.firstName')).
        by(count())
```